# Handle pandas column names in concat with dynamic column name

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to concatenate two dataframe. They have the same index. Column names can change every time I will run the script.

I found the following code which is closer to the correct answer but it does not handle changing columns labels `b` could be anything.

```
pd.concat([df1,df2.rename(columns={'b':'a'})], ignore_index=True)
```

Any contribution would be appreciated.

EDIT:

input data:

1st dataframe:

```
                          2020-02-03     2020-02-04   2020-02-05     2020-02-06
app_vendor_id currency                              
3             BCH           57.389609      57.389609   57.389609      57.389609
              BSV            0.002577       0.002577   0.002577       0.002577
              BTC          162.589959     162.589959   162.589959     162.589959
              BTG            0.010000       0.010000   0.010000       0.010000
```

2nd dataframe:

```
                          2020-02-07     2020-02-08   2020-02-09     2020-02-10
app_vendor_id currency                              
3             BCH           57.389609      57.389609   57.389609      57.389609
              BSV            0.002577       0.002577   0.002577       0.002577
              BTC          162.589959     162.589959   162.589959     162.589959
              BTG            0.010000       0.010000   0.010000       0.010000
```

Output expected (first column from 1st dataframe and last columns from 2nd dataframe):

```
                          2020-02-03     2020-02-10
app_vendor_id currency                              
3             BCH           57.389609      57.389609
              BSV            0.002577       0.002577
              BTC          162.589959     162.589959
              BTG            0.010000       0.010000
```

The issue is the script columns labels (dates) changes every time I run it.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you’re trying to do, can you elaborate?

Comment: For clarity, could you please show some example data and the resulting output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for seelct first and last column before `concat` with `axis=1`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.iloc[:, 0],df2.iloc[:, -1]], axis=1)
print (df)
                        2020-02-03  2020-02-10
app_vendor_id currency                        
3             BCH        57.389609   57.389609
              BSV         0.002577    0.002577
              BTC       162.589959  162.589959
              BTG         0.010000    0.010000
```

If want rename some columns, e.g. last from first df by second df, last column:

```
d = {df1.columns[-1]:df2.columns[-1]}
print (d)
{'2020-02-06': '2020-02-10'}

df = df1.iloc[:, [0, -1]].rename(columns=d)
print (df)
                        2020-02-03  2020-02-10
app_vendor_id currency                        
3             BCH        57.389609   57.389609
              BSV         0.002577    0.002577
              BTC       162.589959  162.589959
              BTG         0.010000    0.010000
```

If want rename all columns from df1 by df2.columns (length of columns is same):

```
d1 = dict(zip(df1.columns, df2.columns))
print (d1)
{'2020-02-03': '2020-02-07', '2020-02-04': '2020-02-08',
 '2020-02-05': '2020-02-09', '2020-02-06': '2020-02-10'}

df = df1.rename(columns=d1)
print (df)
                        2020-02-07  2020-02-08  2020-02-09  2020-02-10
app_vendor_id currency                                                
3             BCH        57.389609   57.389609   57.389609   57.389609
              BSV         0.002577    0.002577    0.002577    0.002577
              BTC       162.589959  162.589959  162.589959  162.589959
              BTG         0.010000    0.010000    0.010000    0.010000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
new_df=df_after_concat.iloc[:, [0,-1]]
```